# OAuth2 Authorization using WebView

Tags: android, webview

I am working on OAuth Authorization using webview for login purpose.
And I know this question is asked so many times but didn't get any proper example for it.
So my problem is I am unable to get authCode.
see my code :

final Dialog webDialog = new Dialog(this);
Objects.requireNonNull(webDialog.getWindow()).setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
webDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_purchase_webview);

```
            WebView webView = webDialog.findViewById(R.id.webview);
            webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

            String authURL = "https://www.apixyz.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=xyz&redirect_uri=http://localhost&response_type=code";
            
            webView.loadUrl(authURL);

            ImageButton webCloseBtn = webDialog.findViewById(R.id.close_btn);
            webCloseBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    webDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            webDialog.show();

            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){


            boolean authComplete = false;
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent();

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

            }
            String authCode;
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                if (url.contains("?code=") && authComplete != true) {
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                    authCode = uri.getQueryParameter("code");
                    Log.i("", "CODE : " + authCode);
                    authComplete = true;
                    resultIntent.putExtra("code", authCode);
                    EventCardActivity.this.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, resultIntent);

                    webDialog.dismiss();

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Authorization Code is: " +authCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else if(url.contains("error=access_denied")){
                    Log.i("", "ACCESS_DENIED_HERE");
                    resultIntent.putExtra("code", authCode);
                    authComplete = true;
                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, resultIntent);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Occured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    webDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
```

Unable to execute this line
if (url.contains("?code=") && authComplete != true) {
}
But really I don't know what exact meaning of this and why it's necessary even I removed it but getting auth as a null.

Also what should be redirect_uri? I have used http://localhost / urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob.

Expected result: Should have Authorize dialog to authorize it and then it should give me a code.
but unable to do it.

please help.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved it by updating redirect_uri. I had a wrong one.